# OpenCV: orientation angle of Camshift

Tags: opencv

Recently, I am trying to understand the code  of Camshift on orientation angle **(theta)**.

In the reference literature of Camshift: “Computer Vision Face Tracking For Use in a Perceptual User Interface”, the orientation angle in the paper is different from the code in the OpenCV.

```
The code in the OpenCV is as follows:

cvCamShift( const void* imgProb, CvRect windowIn,CvTermCriteria criteria, CvConnectedComp* _comp,CvBox2D* box )
{
    const int TOLERANCE = 10;
    CvMoments moments;
    double m00 = 0, m10, m01, mu20, mu11, mu02, inv_m00;
    double a, b, c, xc, yc;
    double rotate_a, rotate_c;
    double theta = 0, square;
    double cs, sn;
    double length = 0, width = 0;
    int itersUsed = 0;
    CvConnectedComp comp;
    CvMat  cur_win, stub, *mat = (CvMat*)imgProb;
comp.rect = windowIn;

mat = cvGetMat( mat, &stub );

itersUsed = cvMeanShift( mat, windowIn, criteria, &comp );
windowIn = comp.rect;

windowIn.x -= TOLERANCE;
if( windowIn.x < 0 )
    windowIn.x = 0;

windowIn.y -= TOLERANCE;
if( windowIn.y < 0 )
    windowIn.y = 0;

windowIn.width += 2 * TOLERANCE;
if( windowIn.x + windowIn.width > mat->width )
    windowIn.width = mat->width - windowIn.x;

windowIn.height += 2 * TOLERANCE;
if( windowIn.y + windowIn.height > mat->height )
    windowIn.height = mat->height - windowIn.y;

cvGetSubRect( mat, &cur_win, windowIn );

/* Calculating moments in new center mass */
cvMoments( &cur_win, &moments );

m00 = moments.m00;
m10 = moments.m10;
m01 = moments.m01;
mu11 = moments.mu11;
mu20 = moments.mu20;
mu02 = moments.mu02;

if( fabs(m00) < DBL_EPSILON )
    return -1;

inv_m00 = 1. / m00;
xc = cvRound( m10 * inv_m00 + windowIn.x );
yc = cvRound( m01 * inv_m00 + windowIn.y );
a = mu20 * inv_m00;
b = mu11 * inv_m00;
c = mu02 * inv_m00;

/* Calculating width & height */
square = sqrt( 4 * b * b + (a - c) * (a - c) );

/* Calculating orientation */
theta = atan2( 2 * b, a - c + square );//Here, i confused!!!!!
/* Calculating width & length of figure */
cs = cos( theta );
sn = sin( theta );

rotate_a = cs * cs * mu20 + 2 * cs * sn * mu11 + sn * sn * mu02;
rotate_c = sn * sn * mu20 - 2 * cs * sn * mu11 + cs * cs * mu02;
length = sqrt( rotate_a * inv_m00 ) * 4;
width = sqrt( rotate_c * inv_m00 ) * 4;

/* In case, when tetta is 0 or 1.57... the Length & Width may be exchanged */
if( length < width )
{
    double t;

    CV_SWAP( length, width, t );
    CV_SWAP( cs, sn, t );
    theta = CV_PI*0.5 - theta;
}

/* Saving results */
if( _comp || box )
{
    int t0, t1;
    int _xc = cvRound( xc );
    int _yc = cvRound( yc );

    t0 = cvRound( fabs( length * cs ));
    t1 = cvRound( fabs( width * sn ));

    t0 = MAX( t0, t1 ) + 2;
    comp.rect.width = MIN( t0, (mat->width - _xc) * 2 );

    t0 = cvRound( fabs( length * sn ));
    t1 = cvRound( fabs( width * cs ));

    t0 = MAX( t0, t1 ) + 2;
    comp.rect.height = MIN( t0, (mat->height - _yc) * 2 );

    comp.rect.x = MAX( 0, _xc - comp.rect.width / 2 );
    comp.rect.y = MAX( 0, _yc - comp.rect.height / 2 );

    comp.rect.width = MIN( mat->width - comp.rect.x, comp.rect.width );
    comp.rect.height = MIN( mat->height - comp.rect.y, comp.rect.height );
    comp.area = (float) m00;
}

if( _comp )
    *_comp = comp;

if( box )
{
    box->size.height = (float)length;
    box->size.width = (float)width;
    box->angle = (float)((CV_PI*0.5+theta)*180./CV_PI);
    while(box->angle < 0)
        box->angle += 360;
    while(box->angle >= 360)
        box->angle -= 360;
    if(box->angle >= 180)
        box->angle -= 180;
    box->center = cvPoint2D32f( comp.rect.x + comp.rect.width*0.5f,
        comp.rect.y + comp.rect.height*0.5f);
}

return itersUsed;
```

}

My goal is to calculate two points on the length axis according to the theory of trigonometric function, so I need to know the orientation angle and centroid, now I can obtain the centroid.

The orientation angle is regarded as the angle between the x axis and the semimajor axis (namaly, length) according to the paper ”Robot Vision” which is the reference of “Computer Vision Face Tracking For Use in a Perceptual User Interface”. However, in the OpenCV, the orientation of the x axis and y axis point to the right and downwards respectively, which is different from the paper, then how to understand the orientation angle? How is it changing?

thank you for reading my problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: have you found the ansower? I'm also confused about that.